# How to reference last cell in a row on Google Sheets even if it is empty

Tags: google-sheets

So I have seen the original post on how to show the last cell of a column using

=INDEX(FILTER(B:B , NOT( ISBLANK(B:B ) ) ) , ROWS( FILTER(B:B , NOT( ISBLANK(B:B ) ) ) ) )

While that works for populated cells, I have a sheet where sometimes the last cell does not have content but require that the old content be removed upon a new row being added with info.  In other words.  If all three columns have content each time a new row is created, all is okay and the content gets replaced; if only two columns get replaced leaving the third column empty, the referenced cell will not show a blank, and will continue to show the last entry from the third column.

Any help would be much appreciated.  You guys are great!

Answer (score 0):

Does this formula work as you want:

`=INDIRECT("B"&ROWS(B:B))`